# MediaPlayerClass: MediaPlayer fires without any obvious code

Tags: android

I am working on a media player app that has a problem. When my phone auto connects to my car stereo, my media player apps starts playing a song automatically. Even though I never told it do to so.

This would not be much of a problem, but after just about one second of playback, the audio stops entierely. I was trying find something like:

```
MediaPlayer mp.OnBluetoothConnect
```

but there is nothing like it.

Next thing I did was build a class that inherits from media player like:

```
public class MediaPlayer : MediaPlayer
{
}
```

but there was not one override that would even come close to this odd behavior.

Has anyone experiences the same issue? Or is it cause I am blind?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Most of car stereo execute a "start()" command when an audio source is well connected to them. This behaviour exists because a phone could connects to the car stereo after the driver started to drive (it could takes time to scan BT devices while the phone is in sleep mode) and the audio should be automatically stared without the driver intervention.
I'm not sure you can do so much because the normal "MediaPlayer.start()" is called from the Bluetooth interface, like when YOU will want to start it for your own. It is the same command but executed in different situations and this difference cannot be detected from INSIDE the MediaPlayer, neither by extending it.

Comment: Okay, that is what I thought. However, the start method requieres a URI to play. How would the mediaPlayer know what uri to take? There doesnt seem to be a connection, or is there?

Comment: The BT Stereo Car simulates a Media Button pessure like when you plug-in a wired headset and just press its PLAY button: you don't specify an URI but it resumes the latest song/playlist.

Comment: Okay, but how come the playback then stops immediately? and how would I catch this? Via the MediaButtonReceiver()?

Comment: You have to intercept those events: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSession#setMediaButtonReceiver(android.app.PendingIntent)
 
Another link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons